# Visual Studio 2008 intellisense for an enumeration type

Tags: visual-studio-2008

Is there a setting whereby intellisense in Visual Studio will also put variables in the intellisense pop up instead of just the values for the enumerated type? It obviously knows it is supposed to be an enumeration. Maybe this is just a mechanism to keep me from putting something in there that might cause an exception.

Consider the following setup: (It's a bit contrived, and I'm sorry about that.)

```
Public Enum PhraseEmphasis
   Monotone = 0
   Question
   Statement
   Exclamation
   CrazyExclamation
   QuestioningExclamation
   Cursing
End Enum

Private _emphasisFromCode as PhraseEmphasis

Public Function Speak(ByVal phrase As String, ByVal emphasis As PhraseEmphasis) as String
Select Case emphasis
  Case PhraseEmphasis.Question
    Return phrase + '?'
  Case PhraseEmphasis.Statement
    Return phrase + '.'
  Case PhraseEmphasis.Exclamation
    Return phrase + '!'
  Case PhraseEmphasis.CrazyExclamation
    Return phrase + '!!!1!eleven!!'
  Case PhraseEmphasis.QuestioningExclamation
    Return phrase + '?!'
  Case PhraseEmphasis.Cursing
    Return '!@#@%@#!'
  Case Else
    Return phrase
End Select
End Function
```

Now, in the code I have something that sets the _emphasisFromCode (obviously) and then I want to call the function. Then what happens when I start typing Speak("HelloWorld", ...)
at the elipses there, I don't like the intellisense. The only thing that pops up in the intellisense is a list of all enumerations.

And now I have spent a disproportionate amount of time explaining this with respect to how much I actually care. However, my machine is really slow in compiling today.

Comment: I don't really understand your problem. Could you explain a bit more detailed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, there's no such setting. The Intellisense lists the enumeration to allow you to quickly select one. If you have one stored in a variable (or multiple variables of type `PhraseEmphasis`), it won't scour your code for matching variables of the parameter type to populate the parameter suggestions with.

Apart from that, the only related settings are to enable/disable Intellisense:

[image: visual studio options]

VB has additional options under Basic -> VB Specific, but still nothing for what you suggest.

To my knowledge, I don't think CodeRush/Refactor! Pro or ReSharper (Visual Studio add-ins) offers this feature either.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no such setting. How could IntelliSense guess from your method signature, that you want to put an arbitrary value to the method, when the signature states exactly the opposite?

Instead, you may declare another enum member (say `PhraseEmphasis.None = 0`, which is recommended best practice anyway) and use that, or eventually declare the `emphasis` parameter with the `optional` keyword to avoid the need of providing it altogether.

Comment: A variable of enum type is not of arbitrary value. I would like to see the enums of that type also in the list.

Comment: This would contradict the enum concept. An enum is a _type_ that consists of a set of concrete values that have an underlying base type. So everything other than listing the values of this enum would not be in line with the concept of a strongly-typed programming language...